# Populate list that is an attribute of a JSF composite interface per JavaScript

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have an existing JSF composite component that should now get a new attribute. This new attribute should be a list that gets filled with the x/y coordinates a user selects per mouse in the browser.

```
<composite:interface componentType="myComponent">
    ...
    <composite:attribute name="selectedPositions" type="java.util.ArrayList" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    //TODO: fill selectedPositions with values 
</composite:implementation>
```

The developers using this component should provide either a pre-filled list or an empty list in their backing bean:

```
<myns:mycomponent id="myComponent" selectedPositions="#{backingBean.prefilledList}" ... />
```

If the list is pre-filled then I will render those values. But the user should be able to change the rendered values in the browser per drag'n'drop. When he/she submits the form, the updated or new values should reside inside the list `selectedPositions`.

Currently I don't know how to get the values from my JavaScript code into the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I have found the answer. Within `decode()` of the component implementation I can access the list passed in as attribute:

```
@Override
public void decode(FacesContext facesContext) {
    ...
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    ValueExpression valueExpLandmarks = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{cc.attrs.selectedPositions}", List.class);
    Object value = valueExpLandmarks.getValue(elContext);
    if (value instanceof List) {
        this.selectedPositions = (List) value;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I submit the new positions using another hidden input field, then I can populate in the component implementation the list with the values that I get from the hidden input field.